# How to use autofocus with ember.js templates?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a simple ember.js text field and I'm trying to add autofocus

```
{{view PersonApp.SearchField placeholder="search..." valueBinding="searchText"}}

PersonApp.SearchField = Ember.TextField.extend({

});
```

Can I add this in the javascript or is at as simple as a attribute in the template itself?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9468061/90741

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Update:**

More recent versions of Ember now have support for this built in, so you no longer need to reopen TextField to add an attributeBinding. As of January 2014 (commit [fdfe8495](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/fdfe8495f738c460b0f1595bc8a37a67e568ff0f)), you can simply use the HTML5 autofocus attribute in your template:

```
{{input value=search type="text" placeholder="Search" autofocus="autofocus"}}
```

Here is a [simple jsfiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/PSx5q/1/).

---

**Previous Solution:**

You can also reopen TextField to allow you to bind the autofocus attribute:

```
Ember.TextField.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['autofocus']
});
```

And then in your template:

```
{{input value=search type="text" placeholder="Search" autofocus="autofocus"}}
```

Comment: This answer didn't work for me. However the answer below by @rit seems to work in my case.

Comment: A little note. Html5 autofocus works only if you landing on that page from outside. Routing to the page from other page of your emberjs webapp will not activate the autofocus html5 attribute unfortunately. (Ember.js 2.0 and earlier.)

Answer (score 10):

There is also the option to use the HTML5 autofocus attribute on the TextField.

```
PersonApp.SearchField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['autofocus'],
    autofocus: 'autofocus'
});
```

See also [documentation on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#The_autofocus_attribute) for further information about the autofocus field:

Comment: Nice answer, but in general, w3schools is not a really accurate source. See http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 8):

Autofocus meaning that we start focusing on the text box right away? You want `didInsertElement` for that.

```
didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().focus();             
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qKXJt/139/

Answer (score 2):

I wrapped this method in a little 1kb package to solve this even a bit more elegantly, directly in the template, without any further coding:

```
<body>
  <!-- all the libraries -->
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.3.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.2.0/ember.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://rawgithub.com/AndreasPizsa/ember-autofocus/master/dist/ember-autofocus.min.js"></script>
  <!-- your template -->
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    Hello, world! {{ input }}
    :
    : more elements here
    :
    {{ autofocus }}
  </script>
  <!-- your app -->
  <script>
    Ember.Application.create();
  </script>
</body>
```

The package is at https://github.com/AndreasPizsa/ember-autofocus
(or on `bower install ember-autofocus`). Enjoy!